# Listing names still the correct one is quess

Tags: python, list

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Here is the question: 
    ● Write a Python program called “John.py” that takes in a user’s input as a String.
    ● While the String is not “John”, add every String entered to a list until “John” is entered.
    Then print out the list. This program basically stores all incorrectly entered Strings in a
    list where “John” is the only correct String.
    ● Example program run (what should show up in the Python Console when you run it):
    Enter your name : 
    Enter your name: 
    Enter your name:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

This is what I have so far:


name_list = [" "]
valid_name = "John"
name = str(input("please enter a name: "))
if name != valid_name.upper():
  #name = str(input("please enter a name: ")
  name_list.append(name)
  name_list += name
elif name == valid_name.upper():
    name_list.append(name)
    name_list += name
    print("Incorrect names that you have added: ")`enter code here`
    print(name_list[0:])
```

Comment: I guess your question is missing a description of what goes wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You almost got it! just need to use a `while` loop instead of a `if/else`:

```
name_list = []
valid_name = "John"

name = str(input("please enter a name: "))
while name != valid_name:
    name_list.append(name)    
    name = str(input("Incorrect! please enter a name: "))

print(f"Correct! Incorrect names that you have added: {name_list}")
```